# matlab array multiplication to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays

```
[a] = [[1] [2] [3]]
[b] = [[4] [5] [6]]
```

I want to convert matlab line to python

```
A = a*b';
```

How I will do this in python and what ' signifies in matlab?

Comment: The `'` operator is the transpose operator in MATLAB. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/transpose.html

Comment: A useful link...[Numpy for Matlab Users](http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `numpy.dot`:

```
In [7]: a=np.array([1,2,3])

In [8]: b=np.array([4,5,6,])

In [9]: a.dot(b)
Out[9]: 32
```

if you want the result still be a matrix, use `numpy.matrix`:

```
In [239]: ma=matrix([1,2,3])

In [240]: ma
Out[240]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])

In [241]: mb=matrix([4,5,6])

In [242]: mb.T
Out[242]: 
matrix([[4],
        [5],
        [6]])

In [243]: ma*mb.T
Out[243]: matrix([[32]])
```

**update**:

If your arrays are 2D arrays, which are of shape (m, n) when you print `a.shape`, you should transpose the second array using `.T`, otherwise you get `ValueError: objects are not aligned`:

```
In [30]: a
Out[30]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
In [31]: b
Out[31]: array([[4, 5, 6]])
In [32]: a.dot(b.T)
Out[32]: array([[32]])
In [33]: a.dot(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9a1f5761fa9d> in <module>()
----> 1 a.dot(b)
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Answer (score 1):

you need `transpose` the first array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
b = np.array([[4], [5], [6]])
np.dot(a.T, b)
```

or the second array:

```
np.dot(a, b.T)
```