# matlab operations of 2 numpy arrays of same shape in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I have 2 numpy array with equal shape.

```
V = [[-1 -1 -1] [-2 -2 -2] [-3 -3 -3]]
U = [[1 2 3] [2 3 4] [3 4 5]]
```

I want to convert matlab to python for below line.

```
Ot = U*([V(:,1) V(:,2) -V(:,3)])';
```

I want to convert this matlab code in python.
How can I do that? Inside V(:,1) and V(:,2) are multiplying?

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: You yourself have asked multiplying arrays previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179499/matlab-array-multiplication-to-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not multiplying V(:,1) by V(:,2), it's just separating them by white space.
code `[V(:,1) V(:,2) -V(:,3)]` in matlab just generates matrix:

```
>> [V(:,1) V(:,2) -V(:,3)]

ans =

    -1    -1     1
    -2    -2     2
    -3    -3     3
```

so the equivalent could be:

```
In [90]: V = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-2, -2, -2], [-3, -3, -3]])
    ...: U = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])

In [91]: V[:, 2]*=-1

In [92]: Ot = U.dot(V.T)

In [93]: Ot
Out[93]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1, -2, -3],
       [-2, -4, -6]])
```